# Canon lens compatibility

Tags: canon

I have a canon EOS Rebel T2i with quite a few EF-S lenses. I would like to upgrade to the new Canon EOS Rebel T6s (or T6si (not sure the difference)). I was wondering if my EF-S lenses would work with the T6s(i) body or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does.  Look at the camera body for a white dot, as well as a red square, as alignment marks for attaching the lens.  The specs on the body should state EF-S and/or APS-C.  Only the high-end single-digit models would be full-frame.

Comment: The last sentence isn't entirely true due to the 7D.

Comment: It is still correct, as it doesn't say *all* single-digit models are full frame. It only says all full frame models are single-digit.